# Normal or Linear relationship?

Tags: regression, multivariate-normal-distribution, generalized-least-squares, brownian-motion

I'm generating simulated data from a multivariate normal distribution with a variance-covariance matrix and then fitting it by either
A) finding the maximum likelihood parameter estimates for the multivariate normal, or
B) fitting a linear regression on the data of the form $y=m x+b$.

The linear regression gives a much lower AIC than the model fitting a multivariate normal distribution despite the fact I created the data from a multivariate normal!  Why does this happen?  And in the real world, how can I determine whether the data is in fact generated from a linear regression relationship or a multivariate normal relationship instead?

The context is I'm studying evolution.
Due to shared evolutionary history, the observed relationships in animals aren't independent.  A relationship could have existed in the ancestor for no biologically significant reason and if that relationship doesn't change, we could see hundreds of species today with the same relationship and it might not be biologically meaningful.

Thus, when we fit the data with a linear regression we use GLS to model the error structure to reflect the species' shared evolutionary history.  This should be the best model if trait X evolves completely independently and then Y evolves as a linear function of X.  However other possibilities are plausible.

The two other hypotheses that concern me are: what if X and Y are actually both dependently evolving based on some third unseen variable?  How valid is the GLS approach then?  And what if it is not the absolute state of the traits that evolve together, but their changes which evolve together.  One common is model is that the two traits evolve via correlated brownian motion.  Evolution with this model means the changes in the trait are correlated with each other, but the actual relationship between the trait values themselves might not be after enough "error" accumulates.  Is there a way to use statistics to distinguish between these three possibilities?